# PostgreSQL: долго выполняется запрос с extract from date

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, explain

Есть таблица на 434 тысячи строк. Поля -- timestamp, xuid и titleid. Делаю по ним годовую, квартальную и помесячную статистику:

```
xbox=> explain (analyze,buffers) select extract(year from date) as year,
    extract(quarter from date) as quarter,extract(month from date) as month,
    count(distinct xuid) as xuids,count(distinct titleid) as titles from sessions
    group by 1,2,3 order by 1 desc,2 desc,3 desc;
                                                       QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GroupAggregate  (cost=144942.51..151455.73 rows=96 width=24) (actual time=123228.641..131120.022 rows=13 loops=1)
Group Key: (date_part('year'::text, date)), (date_part('quarter'::text, date)), (date_part('month'::text, date))
Buffers: shared hit=10276 read=86421
->  Sort  (cost=144942.51..146027.77 rows=434103 width=24) (actual time=123039.396..123075.458 rows=434076 loops=1)
      Sort Key: (date_part('year'::text, date)), (date_part('quarter'::text, date)), (date_part('month'::text, date))
      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 46201kB
      Buffers: shared hit=10276 read=86421
      ->  Seq Scan on sessions  (cost=0.00..104293.80 rows=434103 width=24) (actual time=0.086..1063.351 rows=434076 loops=1)
            Buffers: shared hit=10276 read=86421
Planning time: 0.113 ms
Execution time: 131125.541 ms
(11 rows)

xbox=> select extract(year from date) as year,extract(quarter from date) as quarter,
     extract(month from date) as month,count(distinct xuid) as xuids,
     count(distinct titleid) as titles from sessions 
     group by 1,2,3 order by 1 desc,2 desc,3 desc;
 year | quarter | month | xuids | titles
------+---------+-------+-------+--------
 2016 |       4 |    11 |   378 |    353
 2016 |       4 |    10 |   499 |    651
 2016 |       3 |     9 |   493 |    678
 2016 |       3 |     8 |   492 |    708
 2016 |       3 |     7 |   486 |    719
 2016 |       2 |     6 |   499 |    670
 2016 |       2 |     5 |   493 |    695
 2016 |       2 |     4 |   499 |    676
 2016 |       1 |     3 |   486 |    628
 2016 |       1 |     2 |   410 |    601
 2016 |       1 |     1 |   397 |    606
 2015 |       4 |    12 |   359 |    559
 2015 |       4 |    11 |   293 |    462
(13 rows)
```

Почему сортировка идёт по 430 тысячам строк до группировки? Как на это повлиять?

Индексы, помимо date, построены по

```
create index sessions_idx_year on sessions(extract(year from date));
create index sessions_idx_quarter on sessions(extract(quarter from date));
create index sessions_idx_month on sessions(extract(month from date));
```

Может, лучше переписать запрос, чтобы вместо count был вложенный select? Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

А если попробовать вот так (синтаксис выверить негде, увы):

```
select
  extract(year from s.date) as year,
  extract(quarter from s.date) as quarter,
  extract(month from s.date) as month,
  s.xuids as xuids,
  s.titles as titles
FROM (
  select 
    date,
    count(distinct xuid) as xuids,
    count(distinct titleid) as titles 
  from 
    sessions 
  group by 
    1,2,3 
) AS s
order by 
  1 desc,2 desc,3 desc;
```

Предположение: сперва пересчеты, потом только работы с датами, и только потом сортировки.